# Object Required Error - Double Click Cell in Worksheet to Filter in Another

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the following VBA code to double click in one cell on Worksheet and then get a filtered column in another worksheet but it is giving my an "Object Required Error" which I cannot seem to find:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
'Update Table14 to your table name
'Update Field to column number of the field you are filtering
'Update Sheet7 to reference the sheet containing your table
'Change on to the column number where your click should cause this action
If ActiveCell.Column = 1 Then
Sheet7.ListObjects("Table14").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ActiveCell.Value
'Update Sheet7 to reference the sheet containing your table
Sheet7.Activate
End If
End Sub
```

This is from another post but seems to be modified. I am using Excel 2013.

Thanks,

Leandro

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Where are you getting this error?  What have you tried so far to solve the issue?  Also, Check out [mcve] as well as [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine as it is, but I've made a couple of changes anyways:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
    Worksheets("SheetName").ListObjects("Table14").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Target.Value
    'amend the SheetName above and below and make sure your table name is correct too
    Worksheets("SheetName").Select
    End If
End Sub
```

The reason for your error is that you either don't have a Sheet7 and you should change that to Worksheets("SheetName") or it might be your table name that needs amending.